# bijection mapping a transversal to a transversal

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, partitions

The following must certainly be a standard result, so what I'm looking for is a reference, or the *name* of this theorem. I don't have any combinatorics books at my fingertips, but I could see this being included therein.

If finite sets $X$ and $Y$ are each partitioned into $n$ equal size subsets $\{X_i\}$ and $\{Y_i\}$ for $i$ from $1$ to $n$, and $f\colon X\to Y$ is a bijection, there exists $x_i$ in $X_i$ and $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $f(x_i)\in Y_{\sigma(i)}$, for $i$ from $1$ to $n$.

I was able to come up with an argument for this myself without too much difficulty, but I'd rather not include a proof of a (very likely) well known result.
Thanks.

Comment: The current statement seems false if $n=|X|=|Y|$ since for $n > 1$ there are bijections with no fixed points. Perhaps there is a typo?

Comment: More generally, consider $Y=X$ and with the same partition. Consider then a cyclic permutation $f$ of the equivalence classes. Then $f(x_i)\not\in Y_i$ for each $i$. It seems you are using some unstated assumptions

Comment: I think what you really want is not $f(x_i)=y_i$ but a bijection $g:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $f(x_i)=y_{g(i)}$. There is no loss of generality in assuming that $X=Y$ and $f$ is the identity map. If that's what you meant to ask about, it is indeed a standard theorem about the existenco of a "common transversal" or "common system of representatives" for two partitions. A classical application is that, if $H$ is a finite subgroup of a group $G$, then there is a system of representatives for the left cosets which is also a system of representatives for the right cosets.

Comment: Here is a precise statement of what I **think** you are asking about: if $n$ is a positive integer, and if a set $S$ (not necessarily finite!) is partitioned into $n$-element sets $X_i$ $(i\in I)$, and the same set $S$ is also partitioned into $n$-element sets $Y_j$ $(j\in J)$, then there is a set $R\subseteq S$ such that $|R\cap X_i|=|R\cap Y_j|=1$ for all $i\in I$, $j\in J$. Due to Philip Hall, I believe.

Comment: @bof another way to think of this (at least in the finite case) is by considering the projection map $\mathrm{pr}\colon X\times I \to I$ where $X$ and $I$ are finite (note $|I|=n$, not $|X|=n$, in the question. Let $|X| = k$), and $q\colon X\times I \to I$ is another function with $|q^{-1}(i)| = k$ for all $i$. Is there then, for each $i\in I$, an $x_i\in X$ such that $q(x_i,i) = i$?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I want f(x_i)=y_{sigma(i)} for some \sigma in S_n. The proof I have is that if f(X_i)=Y_j for some i,j then one can remove these two and get a bijection from X-X_i to Y-Y_j and argue by induction. Otherwise, each f(X_i) intersects at least two different Y_j and then basically one can recursively find the transversal elements that get mapped to each other. @bof, I looked at Hall's Marriage Theorem, but I thought it only gave conditions on the existence of a transversal in a possibly overlapping collection, but maybe it does also imply my statement. Thanks.

Comment: @TimKohl I suggest you edit the question to include your correction, otherwise it is buried in the comments.

Comment: Let $S_i=\{j:X_i\cap Y_j\ne\emptyset\}$. Show that your assumptions on $X_i$ and $Y_j$ (two partitions of the same set into $k$-element sets) imply that the overlapping sets $S_i$ satisfy the conditions of Hall's Marriage Theorem, so you get a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $X_i\cap Y_{\sigma(i)}\ne\emptyset$, and then choose an element $x_i\in X_i\cap Y_{\sigma(i)}$.

Comment: You really should update the question. Does your (proof of  a) method of recursively finding a transversal use the fact that the sets are all the same size? If not it might not be correct. A curious fact is that after finding the n pairs and removing them you have n equal size sets where the size in one smaller, so you can find a second family of n pairs (perhaps with a different permutation) and continue in this manner.

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz We assume there are an equal number of sets in each. Assume  $f(X_j)\cap Y_j\neq\emptyset$ for at least two $j$, for all $i$. If $I=\{1\dots n\}$ then let $R_0=\{(i,j)\in I\times I\ |\ f(X_i)\cap Y_j\neq\emptyset\}$ and let $R_0^{-1}(b)=\{(i,b)\in R_0\}$ and let $R_0(a)=\{(a,j)\in R_0\}$. Pick $l_1$ such that $|R^{-1}(l_1)|$ is minimal and find $k_1$ such that $(k_1,l_1)\in R_0$ and then let $R_1=R_0-(R_0^{-1}(l_1)\cup R_0(k_1))$. Then find $l_2$ such that $R_1^{-1}(l_2)$ is minimal, and find $k_2$ such that $(k_2,l_2)\in R_1$ etc. and this eventually stops after $n$ steps.

Comment: This is a consequence of Hall's marriage theorem. Does anyone have the time to explain how? (The first step is to identify $X$ with $Y$ along $f$, so that $f$ becomes the identity map. Then we are looking for a [system of common representatives](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/System_of_common_representatives) for the partitions $\left\{X_i\right\}$ and $\left\{Y_i\right\}$.)

Comment: Actually the statement for bijections between sets partitioned into equal numbers of subsets is a consequence of an earlier result due to K{\"o}nig. Hall actually acknowledges this special case.